# can't remove index.php no matter what i try, htaccess or javascript method

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have been trying to remove the index.php from my url and haven't been successful

I have tried these methods

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

javascript

```
window.location.href.replace('index.php', '');
```

my url looks like this still www.example.com/index.php

My site works if I go to www.example.com and loads in the index.php and won't show it, thats normal behavior. But if I type in it in with the /index.php the js or htaccess won't erase and just show www.example.com

I'm not sure what to try....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Actually does not remove index.php from URL, but adds it. You should use something like that:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

As for javascript `location.href` is a string and string's method replace **returns** changed value, it doesn't modify the string in-place. Thus in js you can use something like this:

```
location = location.href.replace('index.php', '');
```

`window` may be ommited unless you use this code in some local context, where another variable with name `location` exists. And `location = ...` is equivalent to `location.href = ...`
If you want current URL (with "index.php") not to be saved in browsing history, you may use this:

```
var newURL = location.href.replace('index.php', '');
location.replace(newURL);
```

Again: `location.href` is a string, while `location` itself is an object. It's replace method is a different thing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Methods

In general I'd prefer rewrite for this, but https://serverfault.com/ is better place to ask about rewrite rules.

Comment: the js is used in this context $(window).bind('hashchange')... let me try the RewriteRule

Comment: heh, its an odd i tried the js method and it kept on looping my site

Comment: Because js removes `index.php` from URL and your third rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` adds it back.

Comment: yes, I thought of that :_) I had removed the htaccess before trying the js method. Thats why i was a little confused

Comment: Have you wrapped code for `location` into some `if` condition? Otherwise js will execute that code evey page load, which result in problem, you describe.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I am assuming that you want to redirect to example.com/ from example.com/index.php?

Redirect to root:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=302,L]
```

Comment: i pretty much want to get rid of the index.php from any reference of ever showing up in the URL bar ;_)

Comment: @s2xi why are you linking to /index.php then? Why don't you just link to /? The redirect flag (R=302) should solve your problem in either case.

Comment: I'm not linking, but I wanted to see if in the event that I typed in www.example.com/index.php that index.php will be removed.